# Erro ao tentar conectar o banco de dados do aplicativo também no browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Estou tentando testar o banco de dados `sqlite` de um app também no browser, só que usando `web sql`, cheguei a pesquisar e testar algumas coisas, mas até agora nada funcionou. O meu arquivo  `controller.js` está assim e quando rodo o aplicativo no emulador/aparelho o único erro que aparece é **Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**, apesar de exibir o id da categoria de forma correta, não entendo o motivo de estar aparecendo esse erro no console.

Já no browser o erro é este: **Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined**, e indica que o erro está na linha que tem o `$cordovaSQLite.execute`, no controller `HomeCtrl`.

**controller.js**

```
marketApp.controller("ConfigCtrl", function($rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $location, $cordovaSQLite) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova) {
      var db = $rootScope.db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: "market", location: "default"});
      $location.path("/home");
    } else {
      var db = window.openDatabase("market", "1.0", "mark", 100 * 1024 * 1024);
      $location.path("/home");
    }
    db.transaction(populateDB);
  });

  function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblCategories");
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblCategories (id integer primary key, category_name text)");
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblPlaces (id integer primary key, category_id integer, place_name text)");
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO tblCategories (category_name) VALUES (?)", ["Academias"]);
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO tblCategories (category_name) VALUES (?)", ["Bares e Restaurantes"]);
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO tblCategories (category_name) VALUES (?)", ["Farmácias"]);
  }
});

marketApp.controller("HomeCtrl", function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {

  $scope.categories = [];

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    var query = "SELECT id, category_name FROM tblCategories";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute($scope.db, query, []).then(function(res) {
      if(res.rows.length > 0) {
        for(var i = 0; res.rows.length; i++) {
          $scope.categories.push({category_id: res.rows.item(i).id, category_name: res.rows.item(i).category_name});
        }
      }
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });

});
```

Gostaria de poder testar no browser pelo fato de ser mais rápido, mas caso exista alguma outra forma para fazer esse tipo de teste sem ter que estar sempre fazendo o build do app, também será útil para mim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mude o seu

```
for(var i = 0; res.rows.length; i++)
```

para

```
for(var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++)
```

Quando você tem `; res.rows.length;` o loop vai rodar infinitamente; Eventualmente `res.rows.item(i)` retorna undefined por causa do `i++`.